# How to force Jade not to indent block tag?

Tags: html, css, pug

I have an `<a>` tag with an `<svg>` tag within it.

```
a(href='#') Link
    svg
        use(xlink:href="icons.svg#alert")
```

This outputs as

```
<a href="#">Link
    <svg>
        <use xlink:href="icons.svg#alert"></use>
    </svg>
</a>
```

My problem with this is the line-break Jade nicely formats with means the link has a space underlined between the text and the SVG. I've read about using Tag Interpolation syntax to put a tag within a block, but a line break is still inserted for block tags like `<svg>`.

What are my options for removing this underlined space and have the SVG within the `<a>` tag? It seems I don't have much control over how Jade line-breaks. It might need to be a CSS solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the `pretty` option to `false` when compiling. From [Jade API documentation](http://jade-lang.com/api/):

> `pretty`: `boolean | string` Adds whitespace to the resulting html to make it easier for a human to read using `'  '` as indentation. If a string is specified, that will be used as indentation instead (e.g. `'\t'`).

This will effectively make the resulting HTML minified.

Comment: I've just gotten around to reading that snippet, coincidentally - am I able to set that value to only parse a small section of the page though?

Comment: @Stopdoor You would have to put that section in a separate file, compile it with `pretty: false`, and then [include](http://jade-lang.com/reference/includes/) the compiled file in another file.

Comment: I guess that's the best I can do through Jade. A bit involved for such a simple thing, unfortunately...